# Sequelize error: "Association with alias "sender" does not exist on GlobalMessage"

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I'm building a Node/Express app with Sequelize. I created some models and made some database migrations with sequelize-cli with minimal difficulty and decided to add some associations between my entities by adding them to the model files and calling `sequelize.sync()`. Everything seemed to go smoothly until I made a query to test the associations and I got this error: `Association with alias "sender" does not exist on GlobalMessage`. Below is the related code:

models/globalmessage.js:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const GlobalMessage = sequelize.define('GlobalMessage', {
    body: DataTypes.TEXT,
    timestamp: DataTypes.DATE,
    SenderId: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        references: {
            model: "Users",
            key: "id"
          }
    }
  }, {});

  GlobalMessage.associate = function(models) {
    // associations can be defined here
    GlobalMessage.belongsTo(models.User, {foreignKey: 'SenderId', as: 'sender'});
  };
  return GlobalMessage;
};
```

models/user.js:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const User = sequelize.define('User', {
    email: DataTypes.STRING,
    password: DataTypes.STRING,
    username: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {});
  User.associate = function(models) {
    // associations can be defined here
    User.hasMany(models.GlobalMessage, {
      as: 'globalMessages'
    })
  };
  return User;
};
```

routes/api/user.js:

```
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const express = require("express");
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const saltRounds = 10;
const router = express.Router();
const db = require("../../db/index");
const UserModel = require("../../models/user");
const User = UserModel(db, Sequelize);
const GlobalMessageModel = require("../../models/globalmessage")
const GlobalMessage = GlobalMessageModel(db, Sequelize);

router.post("/findOne", function (request, response, next) {
  GlobalMessage.findOne({
      where: {body: 'Body of message 1'}, include: 'senders'
  })
  .then((foundUser) => {
      response.json(foundUser)
  })
  .catch((err) => {
      console.log("Error while finding user: ", err)
  })
})

module.exports = router;
```

I get the error when I send a request to localhost/api/user/findOne. I've searched all over and have found little documentation about this specific error and any advice I've found hasn't proven to be fruitful to me. Any help would be appreciated!